# trying to use stored procedure in asp.net to insert data, What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to use a stored procedure in asp.net in order to store data in my data base but I'm getting nothing and I don't know what could be since I'm kind of new working with this tecnology, the targeted data is received from client side by using an ajax post method, where parameters are sended.

Here's the code I have so far

JS:

```
function referFriend() {

    var user= $("input#name").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/fix/sendinfo.aspx',
            data: {
                funcion: "referFriend",
                parametros: JSON.stringify({
                    username: user
                })
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    console.log('data sended to server side suscessfully');
                } else {
                    console.log("error");
                }
            },
            error: function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
```

ASP.NET

```
public void referFriend()
{
    //Parse client data so we can use it in server side
    dynamic Param = JValue.Parse(Request.Form["parametros"]);

    //Set variables

    //user
    string user= Param.username;

    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(utiles.decodeBase64(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["conex"].ToString())))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("DNN_SVI_SCO_DATOS_RECOMIENDA_AMIGO_SP", conn))
            {
                comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                comm.Parameters.Add("@DRA_NOMBRE_CLIENTE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = user;
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
        Response.Write("OK");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

STORED PROCEDURE:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DNN_SVI_SCO_DATOS_RECOMIENDA_AMIGO_SP](  
     @DRA_NOMBRE_CLIENTE VARCHAR(200)  
)  
AS BEGIN  

INSERT INTO DNN_SCO_DATOS_RECOMIENDA_AMIGO  
(DRA_NOMBRE_CLIENTE)  
VALUES  
(@DRA_NOMBRE_CLIENTE  )  

END
GO
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: When you debugged through the server side, what happened? Did you go into one of the `catch` blocks?

Comment: actually is not catching any issue, it just doesn't insert any data

Comment: 1. Are you able to receive correct username in "Param.username"? 2. Try providing a hard coded name to the Store procedure and see what happens.

Comment: yes, data is passing clean and ready for its insert into the table

Answer (score 0):

Change the signature to your method like, to match the json passed from AJAX call, like:

```
public void referFriend(string username)
{

 ...
   comm.Parameters.Add("@DRA_NOMBRE_CLIENTE", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = username;
 ...
```